# Custom folder locations for Java & wine programs

Tags: wine, java, places

I have customised the default folder locations for Documents, Downloads, Pictures, etc by modifying the `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`. I use a separate NTFS partition to be able to use the same folders on Windows (dual boot).

This works well for most programs. Unfortunately Java and Wine programs do not recognise these folders and each time I save a new file, I have to navigate to the documents folder starting from root. In the past I used symlinks in my home folder to get around this annoyance.

Is there a way to set up these custom folder locations for Java and Wine programs without placing symlinks in my home folder?